# Creating recursive type for union of keys in nested objects

Tags: typescript

I'm currently grappling with a TypeScript type definition. The goal is to construct a type that represents the union of all possible nested property paths within a type.

I tried something like that, but it is still not working :

```ts
interface Address {
  city: string;
}

interface Client {
  name: string;
  address: Address
}

type PropertyNames<T> = T extends { [K in keyof T]: any }
  ? K | `${K & string}.${PropertyNames<T[K]>}`
  : never;
```

The PropertyNames type is meant to generate a union type that comprehensively represents all nested property paths within a type :

```ts
const key1: PropertyNames<Client> = "name";
const key2: PropertyNames<Client> = "address.city";
```

TypeScript is throwing this error `Cannot find name 'K'`.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or has insights into creating a recursive type for representing the union of keys in nested objects? Any help or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

---

The solution provided by @jcalz works well in my case.

I just added some minor changes to properly handle properties of type Date and Array :

```ts
type PropertyNames<T> = T extends object
  ? {
      [K in string & keyof T]: T[K] extends Date | undefined
        ? K // Stop recursion on Date
        : T[K] extends Array<infer A> | undefined
        ? K | `${K & string}.${PropertyNames<A>}` // On arrays, continue with the parameterized type
        : K | `${K & string}.${PropertyNames<T[K]>}`;
    }[string & keyof T]
  : never;
```

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOXnEN)? If that works I could write up an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, it works.
It's exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

A caveat: deeply recursive types like this tend to have bizarre edge case behavior which sometimes require complete refactoring to resolve.  It is always a good idea to thoroughly test such types against expected use cases and be prepared to go back to the drawing board if you run into unacceptable results.

Here's one approach to writing `PropertyNames<T>`:

```
type PropertyNames<T> = T extends object ?
    { [K in string & keyof T]:
        K | `${K & string}.${PropertyNames<T[K]>}`
    }[string & keyof T] : never;
```

This is a recursively defined type.  The top level is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks to see if the input type is an object; if it's not, then we want to stop recursing and just say that it has no properties by returning [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).

If it *is* an object, then we produce a "distributive object type" (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  First we make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with the same keys as `T` and whose property values are the [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the property names from this key and below.  The union of property names is done the same way as in the question, with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).  (And in both the question and the answer, we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the key type with `string` so as to only process string keys to serialize, mostly to avoid symbols which cannot be serialized this way.)  Then we [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that mapped type with the union of keys to get the union of properties out.

Let's test it on your example:

```
interface Address {
    city: string;
}

interface Client {
    name: string;
    address: Address
}

type L = PropertyNames<Client>;
// type L = "name" | "address" | "address.city"
```

Looks good!  Again, things could easily go wrong here if you try using other features with it, like optional properties, or index signatures, or array types, or try using it on types that are already recursive.  I consider those out of scope here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIAUBOB7GiIDkCGBbaBnAHgBUA+WAXlmNmgA9RoA7AE31mQCMAraAY1CwA-MFhjYAb1gBtANKwAlk1j5QiJQHNYAMlgBraOGQAzagF0AXKPE35AH1gADACQT5u1eqYaAvgDpXJFRodHBsPCJiOTNSH0drMR9pT00dfUMTc1gLWCZoADcQgG4QJUZEYyw+OABBFhZEAnYJBNg+BQgclO8Sn1Kmcsrq2ABhABsFZkEWmyZcaC61TRKbLHrG-Hwcuoam4D6IGFgAGUoEFDRMeaJxyYHSEoB6R9hDuFOqACI5vE-YB0+a12mz+AKBG3wfnaEE+QA)

Comment: now you just need a way to also be able to have the correct value type based on the keys

`{ name: string, "address.city": string, address: {city:string} }`